# Change a divs CSS while hovering another div

Tags: javascript, css, html, onmouseout

I am trying to create a very simple javascript drop down menu. The menu works as intended except when I onmouseout the div that makes the dropped down div visible it is loses its background color. So when I am mousing over #m2 I want the #sddm li a:hover to remain active. 
Do I need jquery for this or can it be done in javascript?

http://jsfiddle.net/6ZzK2/

Comment: You might be able to put the `:hover` on the containing `li`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
#sddm li:hover,
#sddm li:hover a,
#sddm li a:hover {
    background: #fff; color: #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cdBZC/

That at least works in FF8.0. The only browser you might have a problem with is IE version 6/7, who may not support the `:hover` pseudo class on `li`s. I'm not sure.

Comment: IIRC IE6 only does `:hover` on `<a>` elements, but IE7 works fine. We do our (2-level) menus like this and dropped support for IE6 when we decided to go "pure-CSS" -- @Jonathan - no javascript or jquery required.

Comment: I wasn't sure, I was thinking it was only IE6. My memories of that albatross are beginning to be old and fuzzy, "walk both ways uphill in four foot snow"-type memories. Thank God. `:)`

Comment: @Jonathan - Also note that the `#sddm li a:hover` selector is [probably superfluous](http://jsfiddle.net/cdBZC/1/); you can remove it and it won't have any effect, I think.

Comment: Mine too, thus "IIRC" - our IE6 traffic is now 0.05% and those are all probes from China.